# ECSlidingViewController resignFirstResponder when page slide

Tags: objective-c, xcode, resignfirstresponder, ecslidingviewcontroller

I need `resignFirstResponder` when a page slide with `ECSlidingViewController`.

If i use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for that. Thats override `ECSlidingViewController` and cant slide page after use that.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to change the existing code. Instead, you should observe one of the notification names used by `ECSlidingViewController`, like `ECSlidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear`. To register, do the following on the initialization of your view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(slidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear:) name:ECSlidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear object:nil];
```

Then, implement a method like this one:

```
- (void)slidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No Accept? This worked perfectly. The keyboard over the menu was not cuttin' it.

Comment: I get the following error: Use of undeclared id ECSlidingViewUnderLeftWillAppear

Comment: Did you `#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"`?

Comment: There are no notifications in version 2. That's why you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

And i found a way myself. May be anyone need that like me.

Thats the solution:

Found that row in ECSlidingViewController.m file

```
-(void)updateTopViewHorizontalCenterWithRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)
recognizer
```

and add that row

```
[self.view endEditing:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is using "SWRevealViewController" you can add

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

under

- (void)revealToggleAnimated:(BOOL)animated

and it will work like a treat!